# How does XCode store which action is linked with a certain UI element?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibaction, iboutlet

I am using XCode 4.6.3 to try iOS "hello world" like applications. I am able to create actions for UI elements using CTRL+Drag. My question is, how does XCode track which method is associated with a certain element. There is no such indication in the `ViewController.m`.

Comment: You need to connect the UI element to its appropriate `IBAction` from the controller XIB. This is similar to API call Ex: `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`(API name is as far as I remember, there may be typo in it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XIB is a XML file. All information related to the UI is written to this file. Typically when you add connections from `UIButton` to its `IBAction` this is also written into the XML as connection records.

[image]

Also, after connecting all `IBAction`s to its UI elements if you go to the XIB file and right click on File's Owner you can see that all the `IBAction`s have associated elements.

[image]

And in the .h file the circles corresponding to the `IBAction` declarations fills with black color indicating that the action is now connected to a UI element.

[image]

During runtime, all this recorded information in the XML file is parsed and appropriate objects are created.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the `.xib` file and hover on the outlets and they will be highlighted in the view.

There is also a little circle in the `.h` or `.m` file that gets filled when an actual outlet is connected to that method/outlet in the `.xib` file.

Answer (score 0):

When you open .storyboard in text editor such as TextWrangler you can see something as following:

```
<button opaque="NO" tag="395" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="5uG-EO-FFO">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="791" y="86" width="105" height="77"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="15"/>
                                    <state key="normal" image="button_image">
                                        <color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                    </state>
                                    <state key="highlighted">
                                        <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                    </state>
                                    <connections>
                                        <action selector="buttonPressed:" destination="YWJ-As-K1q" eventType="touchDown" id="PXt-9J-VMA"/>
                                        <action selector="buttonReleased:" destination="YWJ-As-K1q" eventType="touchUpInside" id="1QQ-SE-jT6"/>
                                        <action selector="buttonReleased:" destination="YWJ-As-K1q" eventType="touchDragExit" id="nqM-R3-G1j"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
```

`destination` = your view controller - it's target of method
'selector' = name of the method

```
<viewController id="YWJ-As-K1q" customClass="SomeViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

That's all.